# Duplicate protocol implementations in dependent projects

Tags: decimal, elixir, ecto, exrm, elixir-poison

I have problems with consolidation of protocol implementation in my Elixir project. To be more specific I use `Ecto` and some simple project called `Gold` (doesn't matter much atm). The problem is, both of them (`Ecto` and `Gold`) use `Poison` to serialize `Decimals` (and implement proper Protocol).

Implementation for `Ecto` looks somewhat like this:

```
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Decimal do
    def encode(decimal, _opts), do: <<?", Decimal.to_string(decimal)::binary, ?">>
end
```

During development there is a warning saying that the module is duplicated:

```
warning: redefining module Poison.Encoder.Decimal (current version loaded from /(...)/_build/dev/lib/gold/ebin/Elixir.Poison.Encoder.Decimal.beam)
  lib/ecto/poison.ex:2
```

But when I try to use for instance `exrm` to build a release, then I get errors saying that I have `duplicate_modules`

```
===> Provider (release) failed with: {error,
                     {rlx_prv_assembler,
                      {release_script_generation_error,
                       systools_make,
                       {duplicate_modules,
                        [{{'Elixir.Poison.Encoder.Decimal',
                           gold,
                           "/(...)/rel/bitcoin_api/lib/gold-0.12.0/ebin"},
                          {'Elixir.Poison.Encoder.Decimal',
                           ecto,
                           "/(...)/rel/bitcoin_api/lib/ecto-2.0.2/ebin"}}]}}}}
```

How should I deal with this? The case here is I actually use my own version of `Gold`, so I can tamper with it to fix it asap. I know I can just add `Ecto` to `Gold` as a dependency, but that seems a bit overkill to just implement one Protocol like this. Isn't there some kind of a macro to check if a module has already been implemented?

Comment: There is Protocol.assert_impl!(implementation_module_name, protocol_name), but I am not sure if it will work at compile time (e.g. before `gold`'s Decimal implementation is defined.

Comment: The problem with asserts is they throw on unsuccesful result, so I wouldn't really be able to check any negative results with them... And event if I was able to then what if the module with this check gets loaded first and then the other one without check - the same issue would happen again!

Comment: IMO this protocol implementation should be happening in a common package (either in `decimal` itself, or in another package called `decimal_poison`). It would be good if you opened an issue on Ecto to highlight this issue.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix could be to wrap Gold's implementation in a `Code.ensure_loaded?/1`

```
unless Code.ensure_loaded?(Ecto) do
  defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Decimal do
    def encode(decimal, _opts), do: <<?", Decimal.to_string(decimal)::binary, ?">>
  end
end
```

Its a little icky but then you don't have to add Ecto, but just check if something else already pulled it in